# Comparing two Arrays containing objects in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have two object arrays and I need to filter based on the property I have.

```
   var port = [
      {
         name: 'Cali',
         type:'Mine',
         location = {
            lat: '89.9939',
            lon: '-79.9999'
         }
      },
      {
         name: 'Denver',
         type:'Port',
         location = {
            lat: '67.9939',
            lon: '-85.9999'
         }
      },
      {
         name: 'Seattle',
         type:'Port',
         location = {
            lat: '167.9939',
            lon: '-85.9999'
         }
      },
      ...........
   ]
```

And have another object as

```
   var child = [
    {
      lat: '89.9939',
      lon: '-79.9999'
    },

    {
      lat: '67.9939',
      lon: '-85.9999'
     }
     ]
```

I am using filter

```
   var result = port.filter( function(el){
                    return    el.location.lat === child.lat
                });
```

How can i loop for my second array.  My data is fairly large in this case.

Comment: You can use child.find() in your filter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array#some` to determine if any object from the `child` array has the same `lat` value as any object from the `port` array.

```js
var port = [{name:'Cali',type:'Mine',location:{lat:'89.9939',lon:'-79.9999'}},{name:'Denver',type:'Port',location:{lat:'67.9939',lon:'-85.9999'}},{name:'Seattle',type:'Port',location:{lat:'167.9939',lon:'-85.9999'}}], 
    child = [{lat:'89.9939',lon:'-79.9999'},{lat:'67.9939',lon:'-85.9999'}],
    result = port.filter(el => child.some(v => v.lat == el.location.lat));

    console.log(result);
```